# Can Yoeman generate files with loops in templates?

Tags: code-generation, yeoman

For example I want to generate html file with the form. I want to pass (e.g. in command line) name of fields and type (like text, select, checkbox) and I want to get file with generated form.

For example - command line configuration:

```
Pass field name:
firstname
Type:
text
Pass next field name:
surname
Type:
text
Pass next field name:
gender
Type:
select
```

Output file:

```
<form>
  <label for="name">name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
  <label for="surname">surname</label>
  <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname"><br>
  <label for="gender">gender</label>
  <select name="geneder" id="gender">
    <option value="example">example</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Or maybe there is another tool that can do this.

Comment: Not sure if Yeoman is your answer. It can do alot but I don't think it can do this.

Comment: Is there any other tool that can do this?